# DoubleClick Studio V2 AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am using Google's DoubleClick Studio Version 2 AS3.

I am using Flash CS5.5.

I've read through DoubleClicks' material on how to build a banner ad using Rich Media, in other words, using video.

I have a parent swf and a child swf. The parent loads the child swf after the webpage is finished loading.

My child swf is organized as such:
Scene 1 with Layer 1.
Layer 1 has a MovieClip on the stage that contains all my banner elements (Video player, video player buttons, text, background, an image, and CTA button again these are using DoubleClick Studio components). This MovieClip has an instance name of "Spread_1". This MovieClip contains the Video player Advanced Component.

I understand the Video Player Advanced component. I understand what to place in the component inspector with one exception, when I'm in "Video end options" I have three radio button options plus a fourth option that calls a function. In the textfield I placed this function "lastframe()"

In an actions layer I placed the code to the function that's called by the Video Player Advanced Component. The code to the function is this:

```
**function lastFrame(){
    gotoAndStop(2, "Spread_1")
}**
```

This function is located in the first frame of the MovieClip "Spread_1". My intent is when the video has stopped playing I want to go to frame 2.

When I test the banner I get this output:

```
**[0.01] Enabler: Simulating page load.
[2.08] Enabler: Page loaded.
[2.45] Enabler: Video event for: 'cakePlayer': EVENT_VIDEO_PLAY
[2.45] Enabler: Video event for: 'cakePlayer': EVENT_VIDEO_VIEW_TIMER
[7.54] Enabler: Video event for: 'cakePlayer': EVENT_VIDEO_MIDPOINT
[12.83] Enabler: Video event for: 'cakePlayer': EVENT_VIDEO_COMPLETE
[12.83] Enabler: Video event for: 'cakePlayer': EVENT_VIDEO_VIEW_TIMER
ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Spread_1 was not found.
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at H100_fla::Spread_1_1/lastFrame()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at com.google.ads.studio.utils::FunctionUtils$/invokeStringAsFunction()
    at MethodInfo-37()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at com.google.ads.studio.video::EnhancedVideoController/completeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.google.ads.studio.video::VideoEventDispatcher/dispatch()
    at com.google.ads.studio.video::VideoEventDispatcher/monitorPlayHead()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()**
```

I don't understand the error and I'm a relative novice at Using DoubleClick Studio Version2 AS3.

Thank you for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the gotoAndStop function is for the scene name but you're passing the name of the movieclip instead.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Spread_1 was not found.
```

Try this if you want to go on frame 2 of the main timeline:

```
function lastFrame(){ 
    gotoAndStop(2)
}
```

or this if you want to go on frame 2 in Spread_1 mc

```
function lastFrame(){
    Spread_1.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

You don't need to send the scene name as parameter if you've got only one.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I do not get an error, instead the movie is playing between both frames without stopping. In the MovieClip "Spread_1" the first frame I do have this set of code:

**`stop();
import com.google.ads.studio.ProxyEnabler;
// Get a reference to the ProxyEnabler;
var enabler:ProxyEnabler = ProxyEnabler.getInstance();
function lastFrame(){
 Spread_1.gotoAndStop(2);
}`**

Comment: Do you have other actionscript elsewhere that may conflict? The code you have on first frame looks fine. Are you sure the path to the ProxyEnabler is alright? (import com.google.ads.studio.ProxyEnabler) You could also check that your publish settings are set for AS3.

Comment: Looking at all the locations I have ActionScript these are the other places I have code.The Parent swf only has one frame. The actions layer contain this set of code `import com.google.ads.studio.HtmlEnabler;
// Get a reference to the HtmlEnabler;
var enabler:HtmlEnabler = HtmlEnabler.getInstance();
// Initialize the HtmlEnabler. The "this" keyword refers to the stage.
enabler.init(this);`
The child swf Scene 1:Spread_1:frame 1 contains the code I mentioned above. 
The child swf Scene 1:Spread_1:frame 2 contains `**stop();**`
All other settings are handled by DoubleClick Studio components.

Comment: Hello @40kilobytes. I apologize for the really delayed response. I found what was missing from the code. 
`function lastFrame(goo){`
 `gotoAndStop(2);`
`}`
What I did to resolve the errors and warning was to place a dummy parameter and I called it "goo". The function was looking for something to pass and couldn't find anything. That took care of it. Thank you for your help and assistance. Take care.